# Images not displaying in Gmail and other web based email apps

Tags: image, email

I am creating an email template in pug. All of my images show fine in the Outlook desktop app (after clicking to download them) But in Outlook web app and gmail. They dont show and just shows the alt text.

```
img.logo(src=hostname+'/images/logo.png' alt="logo" style="display: block; height:64px; width:90px;" height="64" width="90")
```

`hostname` is the local address of the server 192.168.x.xxx

When trying to view in gmail web app I get a 404 for all images.

```
https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/MfZzjvwOhD2V2lA7VFFvjIY9Fe7OsBMxKm5r3zULK1xdqxQxnMv1klagBbX3LLWA41nRjLaxhucFNIdu7spbp8tQHpA=s0-d-e1-ft#http://192.168.1.238:4444/images/logo.png
```

Comment: Did you check your browser's developer console for problems? Maybe these websites can't load images from your local server

Comment: Sorry, yeh thats the issue, 404 when viewing in gmail web app. I have added the 404 address it is looking for in the original question

Comment: Can you elaborate and provide some sources to back up your implicit claim that you expect Gmail to be able to retrieve images from a private IP address space? Is this IP somehow resolvable to your specific resource from within Google’s network…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both mail apps use a proxy server to load the images. But as your own webserver is currently not accessible from outside your own network, this request fails.

You need to host the images on a webserver that can be reached from the "usual internet"

Comment: Our WAF is restricting traffic to specific countries - not USA, so it is blocking requests from the Gmail proxy (likely deployed in USA). Unblock and #winning